# Re-ripping CD with Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player, ripping

Windows Media Player shows track already ripped.  I have deleted the previously ripped files, changed the destination for new rips, and re-started my laptop.  But still the album (all except one track!?) shows as already ripped.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Media Player, please go to `Tools` - `Options` - `Privacy` (press Ctrl+M if you don't see the Tools menu). Click the `Clear History` and `Clear Caches` buttons, then press `OK`. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR Look for items in your music library under "unknown" and delete them. I wanted to paste in some answers from Microsoft Forum post linked [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ripping-a-cd-after-it-has-already-been-ripped/ea077cd7-6a43-4605-82d7-83fa5002291f) in case that link goes dead and I'm looking for this again (or anyone else is)... but SuperUser marked it as Spam, so I'm cutting that part.

Comment: We need the answer info here. I do not know what you pasted so I cannot opine why the system (or a user) flagged as spam, but this is not an answer right now, and having the info from the link MAY make it an actual answer.